# Dired copy asynchronously

Tags: emacs, dired

Is there a way to modify/tell dired to copy files asynchronously?  If you mark multiple files in dired and then use 'C' to copy them, emacs locks up until every file is copied.  I instead want this copy to be started, and for me to continue editing as it goes on in the background.  Is there a way to get this behaviour?

EDIT: Actually, C calls 'dired-do-copy' in dired-aux, not in dired itself.  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think emacs is mostly limited to a single thread - so this may not be directly possible through standard dired commands such as 'C' copy.

However, there is a dired command "[dired-do-shell-command](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Commands-in-Dired.html)" which calls out to a shell to do the work in the background. If you select the files you want to copy and then use key '!' (this runs dired-do-shell-command) then type 'cp ? [destination]' (possibly can use 'copy' if you are on windows). I haven't tested this - so see help on "dired-do-shell-command" for full details.

Answer (score 2):

See also the Emacs function `dired-do-async-shell-command`.

For an even more generic solution see https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async with which you also can evaluate arbitrary Emacs Lisp code through call to a separate Emacs process (which of course incurs a bit of extra latency). More specifically regard file operations see the file dired-async.el in this repo.

Also note that there is work on threading in Emacs under the working name Concurrent Emacs but it's not there yet. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ConcurrentEmacs for details.

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer quite helpful: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13802/10761. Reading that answer shows that you can make it so that `dired` will copy with the `scp` method instead of the `ssh` method (the latter initially encodes the file with `gzip` and that can be quite slow). The `scp` method will only copy with the `scp` program when the file is larger than `tramp-copy-size-limit` (which is `10240` by default). Using this `scp` method in conjunction with [`dired-async-mode`](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async#install-dired-async) is very nice, as it will not only copy quickly with `scp`, but it will also do it asynchronously and out of your way.

Also, I think this is useful: https://oremacs.com/2016/02/24/dired-rsync/. It provides this snippet of code to use `rsync` to copy files in `dired`:

```
;;;###autoload
(defun ora-dired-rsync (dest)
  (interactive
   (list
    (expand-file-name
     (read-file-name
      "Rsync to:"
      (dired-dwim-target-directory)))))
  ;; store all selected files into "files" list
  (let ((files (dired-get-marked-files
                nil current-prefix-arg))
        ;; the rsync command
        (tmtxt/rsync-command
         "rsync -arvz --progress "))
    ;; add all selected file names as arguments
    ;; to the rsync command
    (dolist (file files)
      (setq tmtxt/rsync-command
            (concat tmtxt/rsync-command
                    (shell-quote-argument file)
                    " ")))
    ;; append the destination
    (setq tmtxt/rsync-command
          (concat tmtxt/rsync-command
                  (shell-quote-argument dest)))
    ;; run the async shell command
    (async-shell-command tmtxt/rsync-command "*rsync*")
    ;; finally, switch to that window
    (other-window 1)))

(define-key dired-mode-map "Y" 'ora-dired-rsync)
```